# Dynamic Programming problem of affecting equipment with budget constraint

Tags: optimization, modeling, dynamic-programming

I have a problem that I must formulate as a DP problem and solve.

A hospital is split up into 4 sections, each section has 1 or 2 or 3 backup generators. We have to maximize the likelihood that no section of the hospital fails but we cannot buy as many generators as we want since we have a 10,000 € maximum budget.

The number of generators and the likelihood of NOT losing power:

| Generator | Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3 | Section 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.7 |
| 3 | 0.8 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |

And the cost of having the generators

| Generator | Section 1 | Section 2 | Section 3 | Section 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,000€ | 2,000€ | 1,000€ | 2,000€ |
| 2 | 2,000€ | 4,000€ | 3,000€ | 3,000€ |
| 3 | 3,000€ | 5,000€ | 4,000€ | 4,000€ |

So far I have identified:

n: is the section of the hospital

Xn: Generators for a section n

Pn(Xn): Likelihood of not losing power to section n if we have Xn generators

I cannot identify my Sn and any other important variables. I also do not know how to proceed with the calculations, if someone can explain how one calculation affects the next one it could be great for an in-depth explanation